# Covariant Derivative acting on different coordinate system

Tags: general-relativity

I'm wondering if it is possible to write the expression $D_\mu' A_\sigma$. I'm asking because I always thought $D_\mu'$ transforms as covariant tensor alone.
But that seems to be true only if it acts like $D_\mu' A_\sigma'$, because otherwise we would then have
\begin{align}
D_\mu' A_\sigma &= \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu} D_\rho A_\sigma \\
&=\frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu} \left\{ \partial_\rho A_\sigma - \Gamma_{\rho\sigma}^\alpha A_\alpha \right\} \\
&=\partial_\mu' A_\sigma - \Gamma_{\mu\sigma}'^\alpha A_\alpha \\
&= \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu} \partial_\rho A_\sigma - \Gamma_{\mu\sigma}'^\alpha A_\alpha
\end{align}
implying $\Gamma_{\mu\sigma}'^\alpha = \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu} \Gamma_{\rho\sigma}^\alpha$.
What is correct now?

PS: I came up with this when considering the transformation behaviour of the expression
\begin{align}
\left(D_\mu A_\nu\right)' &= \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial x'^\nu} D_\rho A_\sigma \\
&=D_\mu' A_\nu' = D_\mu' \frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial x'^\nu} A_\sigma \\
&=\left(D_\mu' \frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial x'^\nu}\right) A_\sigma + \frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial x'^\nu} D_\mu' A_\sigma
\end{align}
. Doesn't $D_\mu'$ obey the product rule in this case?

Comment: I can't think of a context in which it would be useful to take the covariant derivative represented in one coordinate system and apply it to a vector represented in another coordinate system. I'm not even sure if that operation even has meaning or if it's simply ill defined. In what context are you trying to use this?

Comment: Not sure if an edit pops up or I need to notify via comment.

Comment: I'd say most probably $$D_\mu' A_\sigma = \frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial x'^\mu} D_\rho A_\sigma$$ is wrong.

Comment: That object ($D_\mu' A_\nu$) is *not a tensor*. I would suggest to use a tetrad formalism or frame fields to do whatever you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can you make an example please?